# Bash PATH and which command

Tags: bash, path

I've just installed locally a instrumented version of sed, in ~/local/bin/ - however I am very surprised to see the following:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian




`which sed` --version
 /home/xxx/local/bin/sed (GNU sed) 4.8
 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

What is causing `which` to return a path which is not the path actually used by bash when issuing the command ? Or am I making a *giant* mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Use `type` rather than `which`.

Comment: Ouch - what's the difference ? It does give the a different path indeed

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then